# DDRMenu - Could not locate Razor Host Factory type: System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-8

We have tried to upgrade dnn site from v7.3.2 to v8.0.3 but the upgrade was failed and while rolling back the changes the DDRmenu disappeared and the logger shows. The specified dll is present in the bin folder. Can anyone help us?

> [ERROR] DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions -
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. at DotNetNuke.Web.Razor.RazorEngine.Render[T](TextWriter
>   writer, T model) [ERROR] DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions -
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Could not locate Razor Host Factory
>   type: System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc  at
>   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.CreateFactory(String
>   typeName) at
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory)  at
>   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.CreateHostFromConfigCore(RazorWebSectionGroup
>   config, String virtualPath, String physicalPath) at
>   System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.CreateHostFromConfig(String
>   virtualPath, String physicalPath)

Answer (score 0):

How did you roll back?  You should have reverted to the old version of the database and the old files.  Did you delete all of the files before restoring?

Comment: When upgrading you should always create a full backup of both the files and database. If something should go wrong you can easily restore. Or copy the site to a test environment and try to upgrade there. If it works there you can copy the test to the live site or upgrade there.